# Undefined variable in PHP header file

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am trying to create a small forum as an assignment. I have a header.php file which will change some text depending on whether the user is logged in or not but it is giving me the following error

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\USBWEBSERVER\root\Final Project\header.php on line 21

The lines in question are

```
    <?php
    echo '<div id="userbar">';
         if($_SESSION['signed_in'])
              {
                echo 'Hello' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. Not you? <a href="signout.php">Sign out</a>';
              }
              else
              {
                echo '<a href="signin.php">Sign in</a> or <a href="sign up">create an account</a>.';
              }
    echo '</div>'
    ?>
```

How do I solve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6wEJ.png picture of the error even after signing in.

Comment: Can provide any of my other code if necessary.

Comment: Session started ? -> `session_start();` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 No idea how I missed that. I feel very silly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `session_start()` at the top of PHP script.

```
<?php

session_start();
// your script goes here
```